# How to implement navigation with BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, navigation, uinavigationcontroller, android-architecture-navigation

My application has 4 screens: **Login**, **Home**, **Profile**, **Settings**.
**Login** is the start screen. Then there is the **Main** screen where the `BottomNavigationView` switches 3 other screens. I made 2 navigation graphs: the first for the **Login-Main** fragments, the second for the **Home-Profile-Settings** fragments. The second graph was attached to the `BottomNavigationView`. And it works good.

```
bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bttm_nav);
NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navHostFragment.getNavController());
```

But when I want to log out and navigate from **Profile** back to **Login**, I cannot do that because these are fragments of different graphs. How can I implement this logic?
I think I need to combine my navigation into one graph.

I will be very appreciated if you share some code with similar flow.

Comment: Why you need two graphs ?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion in a logout scenario is to have

1. a `main_graph`: works as an orchestrator
2. a `logged_out_graph`: contains all the fragments accessible by unauthenticated users
3. a `logged_in_graph`: contains all the fragments accessible by authenticated users

In order to move from the `logged_in_graph` to the `logged_out_graph` you can use a global action defined in your `main_graph`, something like:

```xml
<action
            android:id="@+id/action_global_logged_out_graph"
            app:destination="@id/logged_out_graph"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/main_graph"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```

Call the action programmatically in a fragment of the `logged_in_graph` by using the fragment `NavController`:

```kotlin
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_global_logged_out_graph)
```